# Show that $y'=x|y|$ has unique solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the ODE

$$y'=x|y|$$

has an unique solution for all $ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$.

**My attempt:**

I am not sure if I should consider the two subsets of the domain that sepair $y\leq 0$ and $y > 0.$ But, it is clearl that $y = 0$ is a solution for all $x \in \mathbb R$. But, if I sepair as I said before, should we have, for example, that for $y \leq 0$

$$y=C\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$$

is also a solution for $C > 0?$ Or should a I consider $C \geq 0$ and $y=0$ is included in this kind of solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does " for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ " mean? $x$ is the variable and $y$ the unknown function.

Comment: If y' = F(x, y), I am considering this as the domain of F.

Comment: And initial conditions?

Comment: The equation can not have unique solution for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^{2}$.

Comment: Why to downvote my question? Thats how it was formulate by my teacher and I just put all he steps that I made

Comment: @JuliánAguirre There is none. I think what my teacher meant was that it can be write in an unique form. (using C as an arbitrary constant and for an initial condition given, the solution is unique)

Comment: Go and tell your teacher that her formulation got down-votes!

Comment: @Panja.S. if an initial condition is given, doesnt the solution is unique? I think it is what the question meant to ask.

Comment: @GEdgar hahaha yes, I will.

Comment: @Giiovanna Where initial condition is given???

Answer (score 1):

The general solution such that $y(0)=y_0$ is $$y(x)=y_0\,\exp\left(\tfrac12\mathrm{sgn}(y_0)\cdot x^2\right).$$